# promisified mongoose/mongodb save not returning success to ajax call?

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, promise, bluebird

I have a [great promisified findOneAsync thanks to @BenjaminGruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707762/how-to-promisfy-mongodb-mongoose-findone-before-push-in-an-array-foreach), but for some reason the ajax does not run the `success` function after the save runs..and this only happens with the *promisified* code.

Here's the ajax that should be running the success function refreshStories:

```
console.log('there is a story: ' + AjaxPostData.story);
// make an ajax call
$.ajax({
dataType: 'json',
data: AjaxPostData,
type: 'post',
  url: liveURL + "/api/v1/stories",
  success: refreshStories,
  error: foundError
});
```

And here's the API call that has the promise:

```
router.route('/stories')

// create a story (accessed at POST http://localhost:4200/api/v1/stories)
.post(function(req, res) {

  var story = new Models.Story();
  var toArray = req.body.to; // [ 'user1', 'user2', 'user3' ]
  var to = Promise.map(toArray,function(element){
      return Promise.props({ // resolves all properties
          user : Models.User.findOneAsync({username: element}), 
          username : element, // push the toArray element
          view : {
              inbox: true,
              outbox: element == res.locals.user.username,
              archive: false
          },
          updated : req.body.nowDatetime
      });
  });
  var from = Promise.map(toArray,function(element){ // can be a normal map
      return Promise.props({
          user : res.locals._id,
          username : res.locals.username,
          view : {
              inbox: element == res.locals.user.username,
              outbox: true,
              archive: archive,
          },
          updated : req.body.nowDatetime
      });
  });
  Promise.join(to, from, function(to, from){
      story.to = to;
      story.from = from;
      story.title = req.body.title;
      return story.save();
  }).then(function(){
      console.log("Success! Story saved!");
  }).catch(Promise.OperationalError, function(e){
      console.error("unable to save findOne, because: ", e.message);
      console.log(e);
      res.send(e);
      throw err;
      // handle error in Mongoose save findOne etc, res.send(...)
  }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.send(err);
      throw err; // this optionally marks the chain as yet to be handled
      // this is most likely a 500 error, while the top OperationError is probably a 4XX
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the join callback, you return `story.save()`.  That isn't a promise.

What you probably want to do is something like:

```
var saveFunc = Promise.promisify(story.save, story);
return saveFunc();
```

Which will promisify the save() method.  You could also `Promise.promisifyAll(story)` and `return story.saveAsync()`

So your code would become:

```
Promise.join(to, from, function(to, from){
  story.to = to;
  story.from = from;
  story.title = req.body.title;
  var saveFunc = Promise.promisify(story.save, story);
  return saveFunc();
}).then(function(saved) {
  console.log("Sending response.");
  res.json(saved);
}).catch ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Where should I place the `var saveFun = ..` ?

Comment: you can replace `story.save()` with those two lines.

Comment: hmm..had tried that..doesn't seem to work, it saves but doesn't call the success..any suggestions?

Comment: is that method being called?  i.e. the code within the join?

Comment: just looked into the db and the story is saving properly.. is that the method you're referring to?

Comment: I just updated my answer - is that the code you tried that didn't return a valid promise chain?

Comment: yes that's the tested code..it saves, but it has yet to return success to the ajax call?

Comment: Oh its the ajax call.  I see.  Do you see the console.log statement?  If you do, then you need to send the response object back.  Code modified..